# Matlab Figure Memory Not Freed

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu, memory, memory-management

I'm running Matlab R2016b on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3. Every time I create a new plot (i.e., a figure), I can see Matlab's virtual memory allocation grow. If I'm using Matlab for a long period of time, the virtual memory allocation, combined with the resident memory allocation, eventually reach my RAM limits and begin to eat into the swap space and the system slows considerably. When I close the figures, the memory is not freed. To be clear, none of the following commands reduce the virtual *or* resident memory allocated to Matlab:

```matlab
clear all;  % clear all variables
close all;  % close all the figures
pack;       % Tell matlab to consolidate its memory
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.gc; % Run java garbage collection
```

Does anyone have a solution to prevent Matlab from eventually consuming all available memory? I've never noticed Matlab doing this on my apple computer. Why doesn't Linux/Ubuntu clean up the memory once the figure is closed?

I'm not running into any errors like `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, but the system gets really slow once the RAM is all allocated and Swap begins to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been linked to the `jogl` implementation and its interactions with Matlab. After updating/upgrading the `jogl` packages (described in detail [on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1287267/matlab-hardware-opengl-failure-on-ubuntu-16-04-3-can-not-initialize-shared-res/1293610#1293610)), the memory allocation error has disappeared; Memory appears to be freed appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, this problem was randomly occurring on my Matlab applications too. The most common symptom was the following exception showing up whenever a plot or an interface was being repainted/refreshed: `java.lang​.OutOfMemo​ryError: Java heap space`.

After a few days of researches, I came up with a solution in the form of a small `Java` utility. Below the source code:

```
package mutilities;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.RepaintManager;

public final class Environment
{   
    public static void CleanMemoryHeap()
    {
        try
        {
            final RepaintManager rm = RepaintManager.currentManager(null);
            final Dimension localDimension = rm.getDoubleBufferMaximumSize();

            rm.setDoubleBufferMaximumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
            rm.setDoubleBufferMaximumSize(localDimension);

            System.gc();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
    }

    // other utility methods...
}
```

Once compiled into a small `jar` package, you can call it from Matlab whenever you need to clean up some memory as follows:

```
% you need to javaaddpath before
import('mutilities.*');
Environment.CleanMemoryHeap();
```

I usually call it within the constructor of my `GUIDE` applications:

```
function Construct(this)
    warning('off','all');

    % this is how I called my jar package
    javaaddpath(fullfile(pwd(),'MatlabUtilities.jar'));

    import('mutilities.*');
    Environment.CleanMemoryHeap();

    % ...
end
```

Of course, you can also run the same code within Matlab environment without compiling it into a `jar` package since there is full interoperability.

On a side note, for what concerns the `Garbage Collector`, please notice that even if `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` and `System.gc()` are equivalent since the latter internally calls the former, `System.gc()` is a class method so it's more convenient to use it.

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow; I guess this workaround means you didn't find a way to get the OS to do the cleanup for you? Or is MATLAB just getting greedy and not allowing the OS to clean up, hence the manual heap clean?

Comment: I gave this a shot: I opened a bunch of plots, closed them, and then ran the `Environment.CleanMemoryHeap();` function. It has no effect on the resident or virtual memory allocated to Matlab.

Comment: Have you tried calling `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` before and after running it? What is the outcome?

Comment: I'm not seeing any effect on the memory allocations by running `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` from Matlab before and after calling the `CleanMemoryHeap()` function.

Comment: Ok... well I don't know how your application looks like but I can tell you this: 1) don't call any memory clearing code while you are inside the scope of the method overloading your memory... call it outside it's scope otherwise the GC may decide that there is nothing to dispose. 2) save a copy of all your plot handles and delete them when you don't need 'em anymore.

Comment: I don't think scope is an issue here. My workflow is pretty basic: create a bunch of plots with a script; look at the plots; close the plots. After I close them, the memory is still sitting there, allocated, and nothing I do seems to free it.